# Why is $expect_out(buffer) empty?

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

Does anyone know why the expect variable $expect_out(buffer) is empty for the following code?

Several SO threads say it's supposed to contain the output of the last send command.  Why is the variable empty, then?

Example below:

```
#!/bin/expect

spawn ssh $MY_NODE

# Logs in
# Does stuff

expect "$"
send "$MY_COMMAND\r" # Prints i7
puts $expect_out(buffer)  # Empty, even though it should clearly be i7
```

Comment: `echo` is not an expect command, so I'd expect you to see an error message `invalid command name "echo"` -- what is your real code? You probably want `send "echo \$PROCESSOR\r"` to see what the remote shell's variable is set to. Note the dollar is escaped.

Comment: @glennjackman I changed the code and now I don't need to grab environment variables.  I do, however, need to know why `$expect_out(buffer)` is empty.  Really annoying because other SO threads say it's supposed to capture the output of the previous send command.  It's not and I have no idea why. :(

Comment: After you `send`, you need to `expect` something. *then* $expect_out(buffer) will be populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `Expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. If `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as expect will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.

So, in your case, you have missed to add the expect statement after sending your command.**The array `expect_out` will be updated with the buffered content, only if it expects for some outputs as such.**

**Note :** You have used `expect "$"`. I guess you have tried to match literal dollar sign. This will not match the literal dollar sign, it is rather specifies the end-of-line. It should be used as `expect "\\\$"`.

```
send "$MY_COMMAND\r"
expect "\\\$"
```

**checkExpectBuffer.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#This is a common approach for few known prompts
set prompt "#|%|>|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'

set hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xx
set user dinesh
set password welcome!2E
spawn ssh $user@$hostname
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
expect -re $prompt; # Matching the prompt with regexp
send "echo i7\r"; # I'm just echoing the value 'i7'
# Comment the below line and run the code, you won't see 'echo i7' command 
# as well as the output of it in 'expect_out(buffer)'
expect -re $prompt 
puts "\n-->$expect_out(buffer)<--"
```